# How to get a script to fire when the button to call it is generated into the DOM after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, nwjs

I have this script

Javascript:

```
$('#generateEditWindow').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    var id = $el.data('id');
    alert(id)
});
```

and this HTML:

```
<a id="generateEditWindow" data-id="10">
       Click to show the data id
</a>
```

And this works, but only if the page loads with THIS HTML already as part of the page. I need this script to react to new elements that are added to the DOM after page load. When I generate the HTML you see here after the DOM has loaded this function will not fire.

I have put this function in a document ready function but that doesn’t seem to make sense nor work and have tried outside of document ready. I feel like I need to make this function to fire “on change” and have it listen for calls but I don’t even know the terminology to be able to google that correctly. Any help would be great, thanks community.

Comment: Read up on ***[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)***

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '#generateEditWindow', function() {
    // do something
});`